# Setting ToC depth error

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to set the depth of my table of contents to include chapters, sections (which are custom defined), subsections and subsubsections.

I tried including (currently commented out)

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

in the preamble, but I get an error that "Tex capacity exceeded". Could someone help?

```
documentclass[twoside,12pt,numbers=noenddot,tocbibind]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%margins
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}

%table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp
]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
      \parbox[b][\ht\strutbox]{\textwidth}{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
        \makebox[3em][r]{%
          \hfill
          #2%
        }%
      }%
    }{\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% <- original definition for other levels
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
  \quad
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\thechapter}}%
}

\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{1.2cm}   
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.5em}     

%section titles in the margin
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}        
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \markright{#1}%
}


%header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape \nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape \nouppercase{\rightmark}} 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


%hyperlinks and back referencing in format "(page #)"
\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks,hyperfootnotes = false,citecolor = cyan,backref=page]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\backreftwosep{, }
 \renewcommand\backrefsep{, }
 \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    \ifcase #1%
     \or (page:~#2)%
     \else (pages:~#2)%
    \fi%
 }
\usepackage{enumitem} % referencing in enumerate environment


%bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Minimum Working Example is not entirely sufficient:

- There is no sample content, nor are there any chapters or sections to fill your table of contents.
- The `\colorlet` command is part of the `xcolor` package, which is not included here.
- It contains other packages that are not a part of the problem.

When I run it with these adjustments and some bare minimum of content, it runs without errors, using LaTeX on a MiKTeX distribution. The error message itself seems to indicate some infinite loop, or other problem causing TeX to give you the error. A wrong symbol in a section heading for example: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25596

Please strip down the whole document to the bare minimum and post it here. Also state which version of TeX/LaTeX you are using, when and how the problem started to occur (as far as you know) and what steps you already took.

Furthermore: I assume you are aware of the warning message telling you that it is not advised to use `scrbook` together with `fancyhdr`? Please see https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30696 for more information and how to suppress the error if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly there is no working example in the question, so I can not reproduce the issue.

Your definition of `\mysection` should be removed. Use the KOMA-Script command `\addsec` instead. It does what you want: A section title without number but with an entry in header and ToC.

For header and footer it is suggested to use KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage` with class `scrbook`.

Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. The indent and the number width for the subsection entries can be changed without this package. Note that `scrbook` loads and uses the KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`.

Additionally there is no option `tocbibind`. If the lists should get TOC entries use `listof=totoc`. Similar for the bibliography (`bibliography=totoc`) and index (`index=totoc`). If the TOC should also get an entry in the TOC (this is not recommended) add `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` to the preamble.

The head height should be set by package `geometry`.

For the special size of the chapter numbers (60pt) a scalable font is needed.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,numbers=noenddot,
  listof=totoc,% if LOF and LOT should get TOC entries
  bibliography=totoc,
  index=totoc
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%margins
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,asymmetric,
  headheight=15pt% <- change headheigt using geometry
]{geometry}

%table of contents
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% if the TOC should get a TOC entry (not recommended)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\usepackage{xcolor}% <- added
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\usepackage{lmodern}% <- a scalable font is needed for the special size of the chapter numbers

%headings
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  counterwithout=section,
  counterwithin=chapter,
  tocindent=1.5em,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=3.8em,
  tocnumwidth=3.2em
]{subsubsection}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
      \parbox[b][\ht\strutbox]{\textwidth}{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
        \makebox[3em][r]{%
          \hfill
          #2%
        }%
      }%
    }{\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% <- original definition for other levels
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
  \quad
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\thechapter}}%
}

%section titles in the margin
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}


%header
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{}

\usepackage{enumitem} % referencing in enumerate environment

%bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}

%hyperlinks and back referencing in format "(page #)"
\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks,hyperfootnotes = false,citecolor = cyan,backref=page]{hyperref}
%% The following seems to be not related to the issue:
%\renewcommand\backreftwosep{, }
 %\renewcommand\backrefsep{, }
 %\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    %\ifcase #1%
     %\or (page:~#2)%
     %\else (pages:~#2)%
    %\fi%
 %}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\addsec{Section without number}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[4-6]
\addsec{Section without number}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]